# How do i launch java website on bluehost?

Tags: jsp, servlets, bluehost

I have uploaded my java files on bluehost via ftp and its running index.jsp but its showing code instead of html screen.I have installed jdk 11 already but still nothing is working.I also tried to upload war file but i think it cannot be uploaded on bluehost.

Comment: Please read the descriptions of the tags you use. [tag:bluehost] says: DO NOT USE THIS TAG! Bluehost is a hosting provider. Use tags specific to your CODING problem.

Answer (score 0):

Bluehost shared tier will not execute JSP. You will probably need something like Apache Tomcat to execute and serve the pages as a server ( see https://blog.udemy.com/apache-tomcat-tutorial )